# how can I encrypt an entire column

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

I'm setting up a mail server and I'm mysql for the passwords table. Currently it's secured using the ENCRYPT() function however I have a large CSV I'd like to import where the passwords are all plain text. Is there any way I could import these as plain text and then run a query to run ENCRYPT() on the whole column and update everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a simple update:

```
UPDATE your_table SET password_col = ENCRYPT(password_col,'some salt')
```

Or, if you are using [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to populate the table, you can encrypt the passwords then:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/data.csv' INTO TABLE your_table 
(col1,...,@password,...,coln) 
set password_col = ENCRYPT(@password,'some salt')
```