# How to mysql database encrypt and use in Coldfusion

Tags: mysql, encryption, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Our client sends CSV file (average 0.3 million records) that file. we import in our mysql database.

Is there a way while importing data from CSV file, I can encrypt (SHA1)??
How can I send queries(select,insert & update) to database? from coldfusion or mysql.

if we can't encrypt data while importing from CSV file. what is the solution?
This new requirement came from client recently, after importing data from csv file. we have to dispose of csv file properly from our system.

Database schema already exist and current data that we have to encrypt and upcoming CSV data also.

Comment: Take a look at this link http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/encrypt-mysql-data-using-aes-techniques/

Comment: If it's a mysql function, load the file into a staging table and encrypt it there.

Comment: @scott   this is the problem I don't know where to start yesterday new requirements came in from client since then i'm looking solution I never done this before  Thanks everyone for quick reply ...

Comment: @RSSCE - It is certainly a valid question, but it is way [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) to be answered in a single S.O. post, and is likely to be closed.  Start by doing a search on "mysql encrypt on import" and see what is possible.  A five second search turned up [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3789715/104223) which suggests it might be possible when using `LOAD DATA INFILE`.  Also, look into the [available encryption functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html) in the MySQL documentation and go from there.

Comment: @ Keshav jha im trying those examples                                               INSERT INTO  en_phoneBook_encrypted` 

(fname,Lname,cell)
select 
(
AES_ENCRYPT(fname,'ph2015'),
AES_ENCRYPT(Lname,'ph2015'),
AES_ENCRYPT(cell,'ph2015'));
from en_phoneBook


select 
AES_DECRYPT(fname,'ph2015'),
AES_DECRYPT(Lname,'ph2015'),
AES_DECRYPT(cell,'ph2015')
from  en_phoneBook_encrypted

Result coming

fname  -  lname - cell
BLOB -  BLOB - BLOB

Comment: @leigh thanks it is very helpful link but still same issue why im getting BLOB when im trying to decrypt ??

Comment: (Edit) @RSSCE - Large blocks of code are not very visible in comments. Can you please add your code, actual vs expected results, and any error messages to [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33161861/edit)?

Comment: WORKS :::: -)  guys tell me if it is right thing to do ....  code i'll send 2nd box ???.... for my company I have to design they system which they can automate the processes ... when ever new client comes we have to encrypt all the databases ....I need so suggestion

Comment: INSERT INTO  en_phoneBook_encrypted` 

(fname,Lname,cell)
select 
(
AES_ENCRYPT(fname,'ph2015'),
AES_ENCRYPT(Lname,'ph2015'),
AES_ENCRYPT(cell,'ph2015'));
from en_phoneBook


select 
CAST(AES_DECRYPT(fname,'ph2015')AS CHAR (50)),
CAST(AES_DECRYPT(Lname,'ph2015')AS CHAR (50)),
CAST(AES_DECRYPT(cell,'ph2015')AS CHAR (50))
from  en_phoneBook_encrypted

Comment: Code belongs **in the question**, not the comments. Comments are considered temporary and may deleted.

Comment: `INSERT INTO en_phoneBook_encrypted` `(fname,Lname,cell) select ` `( AES_ENCRYPT(fname,'ph2015'), AES_ENCRYPT`(Lname,'ph2015'), `AES_ENCRYPT(cell,'ph2015')); from en_phoneBook ` `select CAST(AES_DECRYPT(fname,'ph2015')AS CHAR (50)),` `CAST(AES_DECRYPT(Lname,'ph2015')AS CHAR (50)),` `CAST(AES_DECRYPT(cell,'ph2015')AS CHAR (50)) from` `en_phoneBook_encrypted`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DATABASE:

INSERT:

```
 INSERT INTO en_phoneBook_encrypted 
    (fname,Lname,cell) 
    Values
    (AES_ENCRYPT(fname,'ph2015'),
    AES_ENCRYPT(Lname,'ph2015'), 
    AES_ENCRYPT(cell,'ph2015')) 
    from en_phoneBook_encrypted
```

SELECT:

```
select CAST(AES_DECRYPT(fname,'ph2015')AS CHAR (50)) AS FirstName, 
CAST(AES_DECRYPT(Lname,'ph2015')AS CHAR (50)) AS LastName, 
CAST(AES_DECRYPT(cell,'ph2015')AS CHAR (50)) AS CellNumber 
from en_phoneBook_encrypted
```

COLDFUSION:

INSERT:

```
<cfquery>
INSERT INTO  en_phoneBook_encrypted
(fname,Lname,cell) 
Values
(
  AES_ENCRYPT('21234562','dbkey'),  
  AES_ENCRYPT('ABC','dbkey'),  
  AES_ENCRYPT('XYZ','dbkey') 
);
</cfquery>
```

UPDATE:

```
<cfquery   result="upd" >
        UPDATE en_phoneBook_encrypted
            SET 
            fname   = AES_ENCRYPT('ABC','dbkey')
            ,Lname  = AES_ENCRYPT('XYZ','dbkey')
            ,cell   = AES_ENCRYPT('123','dbkey')    
            where  CAST(AES_DECRYPT(PKID,'dbkey')  AS CHAR(50)) = '2123456' 
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#upd#">
```

Hope it will help someone :)

---

Comment: `<cfset pid = 0000233>
<cfset kk = ''ph2015''>

<cfquery result="r">
    select *  from  
    en_phoneBook_encrypted  
    where
    pidpk = <cfqueryparam value="CAST(AES_DECRYPT('#pid#','#kk#')  AS CHAR(50))"  cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"/> 
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#r#">`

Comment: can you please help me ... im not getting output no error coming also

Comment: @rssce - Hard to make heads or tails of that much code squashed into comment blocks. Use the "edit" link beneath your question to add it there.